# Normalizers of abelian Sylows in simple groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, sporadic-groups

Suppose $G$ is a (nonabelian) finite simple group and $p$ is a prime such that the $p$-Sylow in $G$ is abelian. What can be said about its normalizer? I'm particularly interested in lower bounds on the normalizer. For example, in many (all?) examples where the $p$-Sylow is cyclic of order $p$, the normalizer contains (in fact, often it is equal to) the semidirect product $p : n$ where $n = (p-1)/2$ is the group of squares mod $p$, i.e. the normalizer is the upper Borel in $PGL(2,GF(p))$. If the behaviour is different between the sporadic and Lie-type cases, then I would like to hear about the sporadic groups.

Comment: On the other hand, if $p=2^n-1$ is a Mersenne prime, then the normalizer of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of ${\rm PSL}(2,2^n)$ has order $2p$, and you can't get any lower than that in a simple group.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: The irreducibility has been checked for p>2 using CFSG. D. Gorenstein and R. Lyons, Memoirs Amer. Math. Soc. 276 (1983), p. 158.

Comment: Revision of earlier comment: Thanks to Richard Lyons, I can confirm that when $P$ is a non-trivial Abelian Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite simple group $G$ and $V$ is the subgroup of $P$ generated by its elements of order $p,$ the action of $N_{G}(V)/C_{G}(V)$ on $V$ is faithful and irreducible (not necessarily absolutely irreducible). This is a result of Goldschmidt for $p=2,$ and of Gorenstein and Lyons for $p >2.$

Comment: S.D. Smith and A.P. Tyrer prove (without CFSG!)  that if $P$ is a noncyclic abelian Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite simple group G, with $p>2$, then $|N_G(P)/C_G(P)|>2$. J. Alg. 26 (1973).